# In "To" header same Address display two times in mail when using php mailer

Tags: phpmailer, outlook-2007, php

When i send mail to ok@gmail.com using php mailer
then In "To" header same Address display two times in mail

Like This:
To: ok@gmail.com; ok@gmail.com

simple i used this:

```
$mail->AddAddress("ok@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddAddress must contain 2 values receiver mail and name.

```
$mail->AddAddress("ok@gmail.com", "Mr. John Smith");
```

When you don't set name the mail is used for both things mail and name.

Comment: @okconfused his answer is correct. if you want to know something else, then rephrase the question

Comment: When you send mail you have to set Receiver Mail and Receiver Name.
How cleaner to say it ?